# Data access in background process in Desktop Bridge

Tags: desktop-bridge

I've started to build a desktop bridge application with a background process in win32 (for specific reasons)  and a UWP/JS front-end.

For local data store, I will use SQLite. Both processes (win32/UWP) would read or update data.I know that I can access SQLite in UWP side, but I use Dapper which is not compatible with UWP platform. I need also to have a single writer because of SQLite.

I'm thinking to use the Dapper-SQLite in the Win32 process and to create an interface for the data objects, to be called asynchronously from the UWP front-end. Am I correct with this approach? any problems?
Hope my question is understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm thinking to use the Dapper-SQLite in the Win32 process and to create an interface for the data objects

In DesktopBridge there is an official sample called [Northwind Sample – UWP app connecting to SQL Server](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/SQLServer). It shows us the same scenario like what you want. You can check the code in sqlbridge folder. Here you need to build a appservice which will communicate the data between your win32 app and UWP app. You can follow it to build your app.